# Timezone Issue In Sequelize Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want Sequelize to use my local time for reading and writing to database.
in Sequelize config file I added  timezone: "+04:30", but it is just for writing in database.
for writing in database when i add

```js
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false, // -->Add this line. for reading from database
  },
```

i get this error :

**Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection**

full config file :

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("db", "root", "", {
  dialect: "mysql",
  port: process.env.SQL_PORT,
  host: "localhost",
  charset: "utf8",
  collate: "utf8_persian_ci",
  logging: false,
  dialectOptions: {
    useUTC: false, // -->Add this line. for reading from database
  },
   timezone: "+04:30",
});
```

Comment: This is because mysql doesn't support `useUTC` option. You can check the full list of available options for mysql here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options

Comment: @ArkarAung So what can I do to set it to my local time?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it by getter in my model:

```
createdAt: {
  type: Sequelize.DATE,
  defaultValue: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
  get: function () {
    var isoDateString = new Date(this.getDataValue("createdAt"));
    return new Date(
      isoDateString.getTime() -
        isoDateString.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
    );
  },

},
```

and change my config file to :

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("db", "root", "", {
dialect: "mysql",
port: process.env.SQL_PORT,
host: "localhost",
charset: "utf8",
collate: "utf8_persian_ci",
logging: false,
timezone: "+04:30",
});
```